# Is there a mathematical relationship between a bitpattern and the mirror of that bitpattern?

Tags: math

For a given bitpattern, is there a mathematical relationship between that pattern and the mirror image of that pattern?

E.g. we start with, say, 0011 1011.  This mirrors to 1101 1100.

We can mechanically mirror the pattern easily enough.

But is there in fact a mathematical relationship between the pattern and its mirror?

Comment: This is called a palindrome, but I think is has nothing to do with mathematics. Does the decimal number 12345 has something in common with 54321? No, and the same for binary numbers.

Comment: There is a relationship, but it's not particularly interesting - it's just the decomposition of a number into its digits with a given base, expressed mathematically (in terms of divisions, modulos, multiplications and additions). You also need to specify the number of significant digits, otherwise you can't tell whether the mirror of 1101 should be 1011 or 10110000 or 10110000000000000.

Comment: @codymanix: you are asserting *there is no relationship*, and you know this for fact?  or are you saying you think there is no relationship?

Comment: @tdammers: I'm afraid I don't understand.  There is a relationship, and that relationship is "decomposition of a number into its digits with a given base, expressed mathematically (in terms of divisions, modulos, multiplications and additions)" - what does that mean?  the basic question is can I *compute* the mirror from the original, mathematically.

Comment: Ask again on mathoverflow.com, you may get a better answer

Comment: @Zack: NO. Don't recommend MO for these questions. http://math.stackexchange.com is better!

Comment: Gosh, there's a math.stackexchange.com??!

Comment: @Blank Xavier: See Welbog's answer for details. There is a mathematical relationship, meaning you can compute the "mirror" of any number in any digit-based notation system, but there is not usually any useful, entertaining, or otherwise interesting relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment and should get you started:

Break down the definition of "bit pattern" (really, just the figures that make up a number) to see if there is any relationship.

For a number X representing in base B, its "digits" are the values a_i that make the following equation correct:

```
X = a_0 + a_1*B + a_2*B^2 + ... a_n*B^n
```

So for example, in base 10, the number 42 has the following expansion:

```
42 = 2 + 4*10
a_0 = 2
a_1 = 4
```

So then let's define the reversal of that number as follows:

```
X' = a_n + a_(n-1)*B + a_(n-2)*B^2 + ... a_0*B^n
24 = 4 + 2*10 (the reversal of 42)
```

From this we can easily operate on X and X' to see if there are any interesting relationships. For example,

```
X+X' = a_n + a_(n-1)*B + a_(n-2)*B^2 + ... a_0*B^n + a_0 + a_1*B + a_2*B^2 + ... a_n*B^n
 = (a_0+a_n) + (a_1+a_(n-1))*B + ... + (a_n+a_0)*B^n
```

So every "digit" in the sum is equal to the original digit's value in X plus the opposite digit from X. That's kind of obvious when you add something like 42 to 24 to get 66, but less obvious if you were add 67 to 76 to get 143.

I think you'll find that there aren't really many interesting relationships of numbers' reversals.